# Problem with DumpSave and Get in MMA 11.3

Tags: dumpsave, import

I use MMA 11.3 and obtain the strange behavior of the DumpSave/Get routines.
I've saved the results of long computations using

```
SetDirectory[dir];
DumpSave["file.mx", {res, k, fn}];
```

I've checked that all variables contain actual data before saving. Files were created at every mentioned folder and all of them have different size. However, later using the `Get["file.mx"]`, I see the non-assigned variables `res`, `k` and `fn`. Moreover, the

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

returns me an empty list (just some built-in variables) after evaluation of the `Get["file.mx"]`.

Do anybody know how to take the data from mx-files?
One of the problematic files is [here](http://dropmefiles.com/1jC3Y) (~2Mb)

Comment: It works for me? https://puu.sh/AmATY/d061e2ff17.png

Comment: I think for anyone else to better investigate this, we'll need some information on what's behind those actual values. Because with a simple example it just works.

Comment: In my case, the `res` is a table with some dozens of thousands of elements, where each element is like {num,num}. But it should work for any data inside expression. I've used this earlier with older versions of MMA without any problems.

Comment: No doubt it _should_ work. But if no one can reproduce it it is unlikely they'll be able to help. Can you provide a simple command that mimics the dimensions and type of your data (some sort of `Table`) that you seem able to reproduce the issue with, without needing your full code?

Comment: The exact data structure of `res` is like following: `Table[Transpose@N@Table[{i/7, i/3}^(3/k), {i, 1, 300}], {k, 1, 44}]`, the `fn` is a list of 44 filenames and `k` is a simple number.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with that test set?

Comment: yes, it does not read the dump with get. Actually, now I guess that it is problem with this particular copy of MMA. Because it produce much more error-messages with earlier tested code than it was before

Comment: It works for me in M11.3: https://puu.sh/AmZv7/7007c4e492.png. To verify, before you do `Get` you navigate to the proper directory, correct? Does [this](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464) help?

Comment: I've used `SetDirectory[]` and all needed files were found as I wrote before. Now, I guess that this is local trouble with my copy of MMA.

Comment: I use Import and Export.  Recommend this.